# PyQt5 log a signal

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals-slots

I am attempting to create a simple connection between a signal and slot but have found myself stuck trying to call an extra function. There are 2 options I have come to. Here is the code that calls my class.

**(Option 1)**:

```
self.flip = MyClass("Flip Image")
self.flip.clicked.connect(self.do_flip)
```

The `QWidget` is then instantiated by my class, whose major purpose is to log the signal made. This is how I believe my class should be implemented:

```
class MyClass(QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(name)
        self._name = name

    def mousePressEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.log_info()

    def log_info(self):
        log(self._name)
```

What I don't understand is why the `do_flip` slot is never called? This makes no sense to me, so I instead tried overriding the clicked signal via

**(Option 2)**:

```
class MyClass(QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(name)
        self._name = name

    def clicked(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.log_info()
        #add connect() here?

    def log_info(self):
        log(self._name)
```

But with this code I get a friendly `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'connect'`. I can't find any documentation on the `clicked` method and how it calls connect. Is there a way for me to make the connection for clicked to the slot or do I have to create my own signal? I find that this will become very useful when trying to override other signals that emit specific values too.

If so this leads me to:

**Last Resort - My Own Signal**

The class would be called like this:

```
self.flip = MyClass("Flip Image")
self.flip.mysig.connect(self.do_flip)
```

And implemented like this:

```
class MyClass(QPushButton):

    mysig = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(name)
        self._name = name

    def mousePressEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.mysig.emit()
        self.log_info()

    def log_info(self):
        log(self._name)
```

And this works. But I'm not sure my implementation makes sense. It feels kind of hacky. I'd prefer not to use this last resort option, and I'm hoping there is a cleaner option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Option 1** you are overriding the `mousePressEvent` method of `QPushButton` without calling the default implementation using `super`, and this I believe is the reason why the `clicked` signal is never emitted. For instance:

```
class MyClass(QPushButton):

def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
    super().__init__(name)
    self._name = name

def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.log_info()
    super().mousePressEvent(event)

def log_info(self):
    log(self._name)
```

In **Option 2** you are declaring `clicked` as a normal python callable while instead it should be a `pyqtSignal()`. Also this is definitely not the way to go.

The correct way to achieve what you need is to use multiple slots for the same signal, i.e:

```
class MyClass(QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(name)
        self._name = name

    @pyqtSlot()
    def log_info(self):
        log(self._name)

self.flip = MyClass("Flip Image")
self.flip.clicked.connect(self.do_flip)
self.flip.clicked.connect(self.flip.log_info)
```

Comment: In option 2, is there a way to override the `clicked` pyqtSignal given by `QAbstractButton` to add the call to log?

Comment: `clicked` is not a function but it's a pyqtSignal. As I explained in the post, it's definitely not the way to go.

Comment: Assuming I simplified a bit, I would prefer not to connect a number of slots from the one signal the way you showed me.

Comment: Then I would go for option 1, even though the solution I proposed is much cleaner.

Comment: Can a signal be overriden in the same way `mousePressEvent()` called on its superclass?